# Correction in Regular Expression Needed

Tags: java, regex

```
^(?!(.)\1{2})(?!012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210)[0-9]{3,}$
```

I have made the above regex and trying to implement following rules on a string but this regex fail on RULE 1 and RULE 3. It works fine for RULE 2. Correction required

RULE#1  Same digits not allowed.
RULE#2  Sequential digits not allowed.
RULE#3  Three or more same digits not allowed.

Comment: How is rule 3 not covered by rule 1 already? Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: Some testing data and expected outputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Try the following expression for rules 1 and 3 (assuming 1 means you can't repeat a digit right away while rule 3 means a digit must occur at most once): `^(?>([0-9])(?!\1)(?!(?>.*?\1){2,}))+$`. Then add rule 2 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following pattern can meet your needs:

```
^(?!.*(?:(\d).*\1|012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210))(\d{3,})$
```

**REGEX EXPLANATION:**

```
^                   # assert start of line
 (?!                # negtive lookahead group starts
    .*              # match any characters except new line
    (?:             # non-capturing group starts
        (\d).*\1|   # RULE#1: Same digits not allowed (e.g. 515, 330); OR 
        012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210
                    # RULE#2: Sequential digits not allowed (e.g. 567, 765)
    )               # non-capturing group ends
 )                  # negtive lookahead group ends
 (                  # capturing group starts
    \d{3,}          # match three or more digits (This is not RULE#3 )
 )                  # capturing group ends      
$                   # assert end of line
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO.**](https://regex101.com/r/eB0dH9/2)

Modifications made to your regex:

1. Combined two negtive lookahead groups (?!...) into one.
2. from match any charcter except newline (.) to any digit (\d).
3. Added .* to the negtive lookahead group to match those characters before excluded patterns.
4. RULE#3 is covered by RULE#1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly two of the same digit isn't allowed anywhere - not just side by side. And as Thomas commented, that covers rule #3 as well...(?)

Try:

```
^(?!.*?(.).*?\1)(?!012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210)[0-9]{3,}$
```

Changed your first negative look-ahead to check entire string not just the first characters.

Maybe this at least points you in the right direction :)

Regards.

**Edit:**

If rule #2 also should be applied throughout the string, you need to do the same for #2:

```
^(?!.*?(.).*?\1)(?!.*?(?:012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210))[0-9]{3,}$
```

Comment: I now realize - Is there a RULE#4? Namely that only three digit strings are allowed. Hmm...